# Using an global array in a function PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array declared at the start of my code

```
    $animal = array (
    "Dog",
    "Cat");
```

Now I want to be able to use these values within a method. I want to stay away from the global solutions available and was wondering if there was a way to do this by creating the array again?

e.g Create a new array

`$animal_store = array();`

and then cycle through the original array and append the values to the new array. Is this possible?

Comment: `$animal_store  = $animal;` ?!

Comment: What @Rizier123 said or put the array in a session.

Comment: Just pass the array in as an argument!

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought shoud work! I keep getting the following error though when I use the new array in a foreach loop. When I try to use the original array I also get errors. When I declare the array in the method however it works fine (but I want the array declared outside the method at the top of the code so that anyone wishing to edit the array within the code does not have to edit any methods) - PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Answer (score 1):

Any of these examples help?

```
$animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cobra Kai'];

class Zoo {
  protected $animals;

  public function setAnimals($animals)
  {
    $this->animals = $animals;
  }

  public function getAnimals()
  {
    return $this->animals;
  }
}

class NoInvestorsZoo extends Zoo {

  public function __construct()
  {
     // We have nothing to start out with, hopefully we can setAnimals some time...
  }

}

class LotsOfInvestorsZoo extends Zoo {

  public function __construct($animals)
  {
     $this->setAnimals($animals);
     // No serious investor would start a zoo without having animals!
  }

}

// For our zoo to be populated we could...

$iLoveAnimals = new NoInvestorsZoo;
// After lots of lunch meetings and fund raisers...
$iLoveAnimals->setAnimals($animals); // Hooray!!

// Meanwhile

$capitalistPigsRUs = new LotsOfInvestorsZoo($animals);
// Mohahaha!
```

Either way we could then

`$iLoveAnimals->getAnimals();`

Or

`$capitalistPigsRUs->getAnimals();`

---

So take a look at the following example.

```
$array = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Giraffe']; // Our animals array

function animalsInOurZoo($animals) // Our function takes one argument
{
  foreach ($animals as $animal) // Loop through our array
    echo $animal . '\n'; // Print out each item.
}

animalsInOurZoo($array); // We pass our animals into our function
```

Now; you want to pass an array into your function and instead printing each item, you want to **HINT** push **HINT** the items into another array.

I suggest that your function *returns* an array and that you assign a variable to your *returned* function.

Comment: I like this but it it still requires a direct call to the original array

Comment: Okay, well I guess you could merge your arrays? You write in your post that you want to use the array inside a method, do you have a class or are you actually meaning function?

Comment: Everything is contained within one class. The array is declared what I would consider globally however I'm still not exactly sure how PHP interprits it and there is a function which does not take the array as an argument but does need to use it within the function

Comment: So as far as the class is concerned anything outside of it doesn't really exist. You would have to pass the array into the constructor of the class for it to be accessible inside the class. If you want to reuse your array in many classes I guess you could make a trait that has the array?

Comment: The array is declared within the class. I'm not sure if there is more of an underlying problem with my code as I don't see why passing in the array isn't working. Declaring the same array in the function does work though! I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
    public static $animal = array("cat", "dog");
}
```

And now you can use this static member in all your methods

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible

```
$animal = array (
    "Dog",
    "Cat"
);
function addNew(){
    global $animal;
    // just by adding this you can access the array
}
```

So if you don't want to use global, then try writing the array to another file say `config.php`. Then include it in a function and return the array

config.php

```
$animal = array (
    "Dog",
    "Cat"
);
```

your current page

```
function getArray(){
    require('config.php');
    if(is_array($animal))
        return $animal;
    else
        return false;
}
```

then call it in a function u desire

```
function doJob(){
    echo "<pre>";
    $animal = getArray();
    var_dump($animal);
}
```

Comment: Do I really have to create a new file in order to solve this? Could I not create a method that would seek the original array and then add the values from it to a new array declared within the method?

Comment: By creating a new file and including it in a function, u can get all that contains inside that file to your function. 
If you don't need this too, then passing the array will be the next best thing.